# In Hilbert-space theory, is there a name for an operator "erasing" a projection?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $L$ be a self-adjoint operator with discrete spectrum $S=\{\lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < \dots \}$ on a Hilbert space $H$ such that the spectral theorem holds, i.e. for any $F \in H$ we have the orthogonal decomposition

$$ F = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} F_k,$$

where $F_k \in \operatorname{Ker}(L - \lambda_k \operatorname{Id})$.

Is there a standard name and some standard notation for the operators $T_k$ "taking out" a projection, defined as $T_k = \operatorname{Id} - \pi_k$, where $\pi_k$ denotes the orthogonal projection onto $\operatorname{Ker}(L - \lambda_k \operatorname{Id})$?

Comment: $T_k$ is just the orthogonal projection onto $\ker(L-\lambda_k \operatorname{Id})^\perp$.  I haven't run across a nice notation for this, though, so I can't fully answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $P$ is a projection, the operator $I-P$ is called its [complementary projection](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Complementary_Projection_is_Projection). It is sometimes denoted $P^\perp$.

(So named because they project onto complementary subspaces, and/or because of the parallel with set complements: $I=P+P^\perp$ is similar to $X=A\cup A^c$.)